# Ruby regex specify length of captured group

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match a string of variable length(between 5 and 12), composed of uppercase letters and one or more digits between 1 and 8.
How can I specify that I need the whole captured group's length to be between 5 and 12?
I have tried with parenthesis but with no luck.
I have tried this

```
\s([A-Z]+[1-8]+[A-Z]+){5,12}\s
```

My idea was to use the quantifier {5,12} to limit the length of the captured group between parenthesis, but clearly it doesn't work like that.

The string needs to be identified inside a normal text just like

```
"THE STRING I NEED TO DECODE IS SOMETHING LIKE FD1531FHHKWF BUT NOT LIKE g4G58234JJ"
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, so we can see what's wrong with your regex. In addition, you should also post one or more sample strings and the expected output.

Comment: In `"THE STRING.."`, why isn't `"4G58234JJ"` matched? Why aren't `"FD1531"` and `"FHHKWF"` matched? Is `"FFFFFF"` a match?  `"88888888"`? `"111AAA"`? Or must the string be of the form `[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]+`? Do you wish to return all matches or just the first? Please edit to clarify (even though you've selected an answer, as your question my be read many times in future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have two conditions to met:

The length of the match is to be specified with curly brackets `{5,12}`, and before and after there should be not letters/digits. So:

```
/(?!\b[A-Z]+\b)\b[A-Z1-8]{5,12}\b/
```

First, we assure that the lookahead for letters only is negative, then we look for the pattern.

Comment: It's almost ok but it captures normal strings too if they are between 5 and 12. The capture needs to contain both uppercase letters and digits between 1 and 8

Comment: You’d better specify the conditions from the scratch to avoid unnecessary double-work from those who helps you. Please check an update.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the trouble! This is exactly what I was looking for!
Just out of curiosity: is there any way I can count a group's length like I was trying to do? That is /([a-z]+[1-8]+){5,}/ to only keep the matches of are 5 or higher length?
Thank you again

Comment: Of course you can: `/((?:[A-Z]+){5,})/` ⇐ catches letters (five or more.) The problem with your regexp is that you are looking for “1+ letters followed by 1+ digits, all the former five or more times.” And _the capture_ would be the first match (check parentheses in my example above.)

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use positive look-ahead on total size of regex

```
\s(?=^.{5,12}$)([A-Z]+[1-8]+[A-Z]+)\s
```

**Explanation**

```
(?=        # look-ahead match start
^.{5,12}$  # 3 to 15 characters from start to end
)          # look-ahead match end
```